# Converting pptx file to html with links working

Tags: html, powerpoint, file-conversion

I have a pptx file, complete with working links which i would now like to convert to html. The  idea really is to convert the pptx file into a website.

I am using Power Point 2010. I got some tips on how to do this conversion
@ http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980553 and a tool which does exactly the same thing 
@ http://www.ultrashareware.com/Ultra-PPT-To-HTML-Converter.htm

I am able to get an html version,but the links do not work. Navigation is only possible by clicking the slide number created on the left pane of the created html frame.

My questions
1. How do i get the links on the html page to work as they did in the pptx
2. The main page is divided into 2 frames, the left showing the slide numbers. How do i get rid of the left frame entirely?

Thank you

Sameer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in writing it yourself, it's a fairly substantial undertaking.  The most direct method is to export an image of each slide and put that into the resulting HTML with an IMG tag.  You'd also need to construct an image map and include in it each of the hyperlink URLs from the slide, along with coordinates normalized from PPT's slide size to the size of the image you're adding to the HTML.  Or work out how to put links in DIVs atop the image.

If you're looking for an immediately available commercial add-in that gives you more control over the appearance of the HTML, I've written one.  There's more info and a free demo at http://www.pptools.com/ppt2html/

I'd be happy to answer any questions you have about it, but it might be best not to clutter SO with support chat.  There's a Contact link on each page of the pptools site; best to use that to get in touch, if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, i quickly realized this would be difficult. Your comment validated it. I abandoned the approach of trying to use a tool to convert a pptx to an HTML website. The more sensible approach is to build the website to close approximation to pptx using website builder tools provided by the ISP provider from where you have bought the domain name.